# Show ButtonField of gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that have a column that I want show It dynamically:
If IsExpert or IsAgent equal true show It else not show It and I don't want use RowBoundData.(IsExpert and IsAgent are server side property)

MyCode:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvTicketList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table half table-hover table-mc-light-blue" GridLines="None"
EmptyDataText="تیکتی موجود نیست" OnPageIndexChanging="grvTicketList_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-BackColor="White"
PagerStyle-ForeColor="Black" OnRowCommand="grvTicketList_RowCommand" >
<Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="شماره تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentStateId" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="شماره مرحله فعلی تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TrackingCode" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="کد رهگیری" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="نام خدمت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubServiceName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText=" نام زیر خدمت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="strTicketDate" HeaderText="زمان ثبت تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText=" نام و نام خانوادگی مشتری" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="StateName" HeaderText="وضعیت تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="نام ثبت کننده تیکت" />

    <asp:ButtonField Text="بازخورد" CommandName="FeedBack" ButtonType="Link" >
        <ItemStyle ForeColor="#003399" />
    </asp:ButtonField>

</Columns>

<PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black"></PagerStyle>
```

Comment: Why not `RowDataBound` ?

Comment: I am assuming IsExpert and IsAgent is a property in you code. why don't you hide the gridview in Page_Load, otherwise use Jquery.

Comment: @Zaki Yes! IsExpert and IsAgent are property (bool type) but I need server code.and want visible or invisible ButtonField  column

Comment: @MattMurdock Because I have another event that causes after page postback disappear changes on RowDataBound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In page load

```
if(IsExpert || IsAgent)
    GridView1.Columns[9].Visible=true;
 else
    GridView1.Columns[9].Visible=false;
```

Comment: Thanks.. But 'IsExpert' or 'IsAgent' are server side property(bool type)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using aspx i would prefer codebehind, for example `Page_Load` or [`DataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that  `DataBound` is only triggered once as opposed to  `RowDataBound` which is fired for every row:

codebehind:

```
protected void GrvTicketList_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
    grid.Columns[9].Visible = IsExpert || IsAgent;
}
```

aspx (add the event handler):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvTicketList" OnDataBound="GrvTicketList_DataBound" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table half table-hover table-mc-light-blue" GridLines="None"
EmptyDataText="تیکتی موجود نیست" OnPageIndexChanging="grvTicketList_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-BackColor="White"
PagerStyle-ForeColor="Black" OnRowCommand="grvTicketList_RowCommand" >
<Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="شماره تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentStateId" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="شماره مرحله فعلی تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TrackingCode" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="کد رهگیری" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="نام خدمت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubServiceName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText=" نام زیر خدمت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="strTicketDate" HeaderText="زمان ثبت تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText=" نام و نام خانوادگی مشتری" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="StateName" HeaderText="وضعیت تیکت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="نام ثبت کننده تیکت" />

    <asp:ButtonField Text="بازخورد" CommandName="FeedBack" ButtonType="Link" >
        <ItemStyle ForeColor="#003399" />
    </asp:ButtonField>

</Columns>
```